# IllegalArgumentException while adding a new document in Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui, android-paging

I'm adding a new document in firestore. After adding a new document when I come back to my activity which is showing those list of documents, my app crashes with the following errors. In my query, I'm ordering the documents with server timestamp.

> **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid query. You are trying to
>   start or end a query using a document for which the field
>   'additionTime' is an uncommitted server timestamp. (Since the value of
>   this field is unknown, you cannot start/end a query with it.)**
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.boundFromDocumentSnapshot(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.0.0:742)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.startAfter(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.0.0:632)
>           at com.firebase.ui.firestore.paging.PageKey.getPageQuery(PageKey.java:29)
>           at com.firebase.ui.firestore.paging.FirestoreDataSource.loadAfter(FirestoreDataSource.java:106)
>           at androidx.paging.PageKeyedDataSource.dispatchLoadAfter(PageKeyedDataSource.java:338)
>           at androidx.paging.ContiguousPagedList$3.run(ContiguousPagedList.java:228)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

**It only happens when I'm adding the first document**. My POJO class is here

```java
public class BookLight implements Serializable {

    private String bookId;
    private String bookName;
    private String authors;
    private float rating;
    private String category;
    private String thumbnail;
    private BookState bookState;
    private String ownerID;

    @ServerTimestamp
    private Date additionTime;



    public BookLight(){

    }

    //other getters and settes
    public Date getAdditionTime() {
        return additionTime;
    }

    public void setAdditionTime(Date additionTime) {
        this.additionTime = additionTime;
    }


}
```

Here I'm using `FirestorePagingAdapter` for showing those items

```java
private FirestorePagingAdapter<BookLight, BookViewHolder> mAdapter;

private void loadData(){
                query= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                        .collection("Groups")
                        .document(groupDetails.getGroupID())
                        .collection("books")
                        .orderBy("additionTime",Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

                PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
                        .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                        .setPrefetchDistance(5)
                        .setPageSize(3)
                        .build();

                FirestorePagingOptions<BookLight> options = new FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<BookLight>()
                        .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                        .setQuery(query, config, BookLight.class)
                        .build();

                mAdapter = new FirestorePagingAdapter<BookLight, BookViewHolder>(options) {
                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public BookViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                        return new BookViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.book_row_item, parent, false));
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BookViewHolder bookViewHolder, int position, @NonNull final BookLight book) {
                    }


                    @Override
                    protected void onError(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        super.onError(e);
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                };

                recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Database structure
[image]

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot. Beside that, are you sure that all your `additionTime` properties are of type `Date` and hold a date value?

Comment: Yeah. all `additionTime` properties are of type `Date` holds date value and error occurs only for the first document. After searching I've found this github issue with `Firestore`. [https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/106] . But there is no clear explanation. How can I implement this?

Comment: @ShahrearBinAmin I have exact this problem. This error ocurres only for the first document. Did you find any solution? Your provided link to github is also not available. Please reply.